# MODULE_NOT_FOUND Nestjs and Swagger

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I'm trying to add Swagger to my Nestjs app. Module not found error is thrown when I'm trying to compile it.
I use the same code from Nestjs documentation.
This is my main.ts:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Cats example')
    .setDescription('The cats API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('cats')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

This is the error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core/router/route-path-factory'
Require stack:
- D:\BK\solidity\MVPApp\blockchain\back-end-student-wallet-v2\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\swagger-explorer.js
- D:\BK\solidity\MVPApp\blockchain\back-end-student-wallet-v2\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\swagger-scanner.js 
- D:\BK\solidity\MVPApp\blockchain\back-end-student-wallet-v2\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\swagger-module.js  
- D:\BK\solidity\MVPApp\blockchain\back-end-student-wallet-v2\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\dist\index.js
- D:\BK\solidity\MVPApp\blockchain\back-end-student-wallet-v2\node_modules\@nestjs\swagger\index.js
- D:\BK\solidity\MVPApp\blockchain\back-end-student-wallet-v2\dist\main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
```

I'm using Node 14.15.1, @nestjs/swagger 5.0.0, swagger-ui-express: 4.1.6

Comment: update latest version of @nestjs/platform-express, @nestjs/common,@nestjs/core solve my problem

Comment: Post your comment as an answer and [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/131247), so your question will appear as solved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update latest version of @nestjs/platform-express, @nestjs/common,@nestjs/core (8.0.0) solve my problem. It seems like nestjs/cli uses previous version of nestjs

Answer (score 10):

Swagger v5 is compatible with Nest v8 (@nestjs/core@^8.0.0, @nestjs/common@^8.0.0 etc)
Swagger v4 is compatible with Nest v7

Source from https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7499

Answer (score 1):

Quick Fix ====>>

Update your dependencies to reflect:

```
{
"@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/config": "^1.1.5",
"@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
}
```

Update your dev dependencies to reflect:

```
   {
        "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
        "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
        "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    }
```

This fixed my problem. Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else gets this same problem but everything seems to be correct(Dockerfile), check for occurence in both **devDependencies** and **normal dependencies**, for me that was the cause of the issue, you need to remove it from devDependencies if you want to have it in prod(I had it in both).